# Using fetch, how to handle reject properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have the following function which came from the mern.io stack.

```
export default function callApi(endpoint, method = 'get', body) {
  return fetch(`${API_URL}/${endpoint}`, {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    method,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  })
  .then(response => response.json().then(json => ({ json, response })))
  .then(({ json, response }) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(json);
    }
    return json;
  })
  .then(
    response => response,
    error => error
  );
}
```

I call the function the following way

```
callApi('auth/register', 'post', {
      username,
      password,
}).then(function(res) {
    // do stuff
});
```

The response will either be a 201 or a 422. How can handle the 422 the proper way? A 422 would occur if a username already exists.

Do I put all the logic in the first then such as the following:

```
callApi('auth/register', 'post', {
      username,
      password,
}).then(function(res) {
    if (res.error) {

    } else {
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesnt throw an error and here is the code on the repo: https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/blob/master/client/util/apiCaller.js

Comment: The problem with that last `then` in `callApi` is that it turns any failing promise into a resolved one which IMO is just stupid. It should be omitted entirely

Answer (score 1):

Assuming callApi returns a `Promise` object:

```
callApi('auth/register', 'post', {
      username,
      password,
}).then(function(res) {
    // res
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle err
});
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: It's using https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch and it never goes to the catch method.

Comment: @Jose You can throw new Error in your fulfillment handler.